# SpringMVC - Get Ul Element Index On Click

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc

I am looking for a way to get the index or object held my an List on my website so that I can send a POST response to update content.

**Question 1**
How to get object or index of ul element on click with JQuery?

**Question 2**
How to send Object or Index as POST to spring MVC backbone to update page contents?

**Code Snippets**

**Jquery and DIV for Ul element in question**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.result-div').click(function() {
            $(this).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(200);
           //---- some code here to get index or object and send post?----

    });
});
</script>
<ul class="result-class">
            <c:forEach var="offender" items="${offenderlists}">
                <li><div class="result-div">
                <div class="result-img-holder">
                <img src=<c:out value="${offender.linkToPicture}"/> height="120" width="120"/>
                 <span class=result-div-titles>
                OffenderID: </span> <c:out value="${offender.offenderId}"/>
                </div>

                <div class="result-div-oinfo">
                <ul class="info-list1">
                <li><span class=result-div-titles>
                First Name: </span> <c:out value="${offender.firstName}"/>
                </li>
                <li><span class=result-div-titles>
                Last Name: </span> <c:out value="${offender.lastName}"/></li>
                <li><span class=result-div-titles>
                Middle Name: </span><c:out value="${offender.middleName}"/>
                </li>
                <li><span class=result-div-titles>
                DOB: </span>
                </li>
                <li><span class=result-div-titles>
                Sex: </span>
                </li>
                <li><span class=result-div-titles>
                Risk Level: </span><c:out value="${offender.riskLevel}"/>
                </li>
                <li><span class=result-div-titles>
                Designation: </span>
                </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="info-list2">
                <li><span class=result-div-titles>
                Race: </span></li>
                <li><span class=result-div-titles>
                Ethnicity: </span></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="result-address">
                <span class=result-div-titles>
                Primary Address: </span><br>
                <c:out value="${offender.primaryAddress.address_line1}"/><br>
                <c:out value="${offender.primaryAddress.city}"/>, 
                 New York <c:out value="${offender.primaryAddress.zipcode}"/>
                </div>
                </div>
                 </div></li>

            </c:forEach>
            </ul>
```

**Question restated for clarity**

**1) How to get index or object held in div/ul elements using Jquery?**

**2) Best way to send Object of Ul index to Java backbone ? Maybe POST?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("li")` is an object collection of `<li>` and  the first element of `<li>` is
`$("li").eq(0)` which is also an object ( have it's own properties) and it's numerical index position is `$("li").eq(0).index()`

In spring mvc url is handled via request mapping to a certain controller method :

I would say in your JQuery, you can bring the index of `<div>` via url parameter, to be processed by a controller method :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.result-div').click(function() {
            $(this).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(200);

         var currentClickedIndex = this.index();
   window.location.href='andPageToProcessThisIndex.jsp?idx = '+currentClickedIndex ;

    });
});
```

and assuming thisis the controller method that will catch the index and process it later :

```
@RequestMapping("andPageToProcessThisIndex")
public ModelAndView goToView (@RequestParam ("idx") String idx){
 return new ModelAndView ("aViewPage","idx",idx) ;
 }
```

Comment: Sounds great let me try I'll get back to you if I have any problems!